# How to delete object with a prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to delete an object that was created with a prototype object. The delete seems to not be working. After the call to delete, the object is still there...
The object is created by calling:

```
utils.createWithProto = function (o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
```

The following below is used to create the object.

```
// Create a new object using DashboardControl as the prototype
// A unique ID is set in newControl.config.controlId if it was not passed in config
var proto = new DashboardControl(config);
var newControl = Utils.createWithProto(proto);

// Create a collection of Volume models
newControl.volumeCollection = new VolumeCollection();
newControl.volumeCollection.init(newControl.config);

// Create a view
newControl.volumeView = new VolumeView(newControl, newControl.volumeCollection);
```

I'm manually calling delete on the volumeCollection and volumeView items, that works fine. But the delete of the object itself as a last step is not working:

```
deleteObject: function(object) {
    object.volumeCollection.stop();
    delete object.volumeCollection;
    object.volumeView.stop();
    delete object.volumeView;
    //delete object.config;
    delete object.prototype;
    delete object;
    object = null;
}
```

How do I go about deleting this derived object?

Comment: Where's the part where you delete?

Answer (score 3):

`delete` will only delete *properties* on an object. If you want to delete a value on a *variable*, then let it go out of scope or assign a new value to it.

Once all the properties and variables referencing an object have gone, the object will be garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you Quentin.
What remains after deleting the volumeView and volumeCollection is a member "____proto____". I guess that if I get rid of(delete) that, the object will have effectively been deleted. But that step I couldn't yet take.

Answer (score 1):

> If the property is an object reference, the delete command deletes the
>   property but not the object. The garbage collector will take care of
>   the object if it has no other references to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where delete works :

```
var b = [1,2,3];

delete b[2];          // b becomes [3, 4, undefined]
```

When you want to clear memory used by b, you simply re-assign it to nothing.

```
 b = null;
```

Browser's garbage collector will take care of it from there on.